# Azure data factory - mapping data flows regex implementation to format a number

Tags: regex, azure-data-factory, regexp-replace, azure-mapping-data-flow

I am creating a mapping data flow where I have a phone number column which can contain values like
(555) 555-1234 or
(555)555-1234 or
555555-1234

I want to extract numbers from this value. How can that be done. I have tried the below function with different variations but nothing is working.

regexExtract("(555) 555-1234",'\d+)')

regexExtract("(555) 555-1234",'(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)')

Comment: Try `^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}) ?\d{2,3}-\d{4}$`, see https://regex101.com/r/Xv22k1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have multiple phone formats, you need to remove parentheses and spaces and dashes so you need multiple statements of regexExtract which will make your solution complicated.

instead, i suggest that you use **regexReplace**, mainly keeping only digits.
i tried it in ADF and it worked, for the sake of the demo, i added a derived column `phoneNumber` with a value:   `(555) 555-1234`
in the derived column activity i added a new column '`validPhoneNumber`' with a regexReplace value like so:

```
regexReplace(phoneNumber,'[^0-9]', '')
```

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#regexReplace